# remove duplicated span tag content

Tags: python-3.x, select, beautifulsoup

```
  <div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
                            <span>13,978</span>
                            <span>(</span><span 
                            class="change_increase">+2.3% 
                            </span><span>)</span>                       
  </div>

 <div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">

                            <span>99,585</span>
                            <span>(</span><span 
                            class="change_increase">+0.6% 
                            </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

  <div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">

                            <span>12121</span>
                            <span>(</span><span 
                            class="change_increase">+2.3% 
                            </span><span>)</span>                       
 </div>

    <div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right"> 
                            <span>99,222</span>
                            <span>(</span><span 
                           class="change_increase">+0.6% 
                        </span><span>)</span>                       

    </div>
```

I tried the code below:

```
    text=[]
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    TicketNuber=soup.find_all("div")
    for div in TicketNuber:
            text.append(div.find("span"))
    it prints out:[
     '13,978',
     '13,978',
     '99,585',
     '12,121'
     '12,121'
     '99,222'
     ]
```

Not sure why the first number will print out twice. I only want the number ['13,978','99492','12,121','99,222']. there is no duplicate number in the same tag

Answer (score 1):

When I do this:

```
text = []

TicketNumber = soup.find_all("div")
for div in TicketNumber:
    text.append(div.find("span").get_text())

print(text)
```

I get this:

```
['13,978', '99,585', '12,121', '99,222']
```

Could you please give this a shot and confirm if this works?